# Update Table via Binding Model in ASP .Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, model-binding

I want to change creating table conditions like this:

There is a way of creating table via list model. My aim, when input a number in Determine Number Text Box, then the table will change according to Determine Number.

Example: If DetermineNumber is 5, then the table's row is 5 and the structure of this table will be same like older (A column  0 and B column  0++).

Here is my code:

```
//My Home Controller

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyWeb.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyWeb.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var send_class = new GetChecking();
            var send_list = new List<MyClass>();
            send_class.DetermineNumber = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < send_class.DetermineNumber; i++)
            {
                send_list.Add(new MyClass { A = 0, B = i });
            }
            send_class.GetMyList = send_list;
            return View(send_class);
        }
    }
}
//My Class

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyWeb.Models
{
    public class GetChecking
    {
        public int DetermineNumber { get; set; }
        public List<MyClass> GetMyList { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is my Index.cshtml:

```
    <!-- My Index.cshtml -->

@model GetChecking
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div align="center">
        <table id="tablex">
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tablex Row Count</td>
                        <td asp-for="@Model.DetermineNumber">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.DetermineNumber)</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div align="center">
        <table id="tablex">
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="2">My Main</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1">A</th>
                    <th colspan="1">B</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DetermineNumber; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td asp-for="@Model.GetMyList[i].A">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.GetMyList[i].A)</td>
                        <td asp-for="@Model.GetMyList[i].B">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.GetMyList[i].B)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear! Please explain it further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the table in a partial view, when you change the input in Index view, it calls the action to return the partial view with corresponding model data.

It will not refresh the page each time you change the number.Refer to below demo:

1.Index View:

```
@model GetChecking

<div align="center">
    <table id="tablex">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tablex Row Count</td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.DetermineNumber" id="number" name="number" oninput="changeNum()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div align="center" id="indexWrapper">
    <partial name="_IndexPartial" model="@Model" />
</div>

@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function changeNum() {
        var num = $("#number").val();

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/GetTable?Num=" + num,
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#indexWrapper").html(res)
                }
            });
    }
</script>
}
```

2.Add a partial view `_IndexPartial.cshtml` in `Shared` folder

```
@model GetChecking
<table id="tablex">
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2">My Main</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1">A</th>
            <th colspan="1">B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DetermineNumber; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td asp-for="@Model.GetMyList[i].A">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.GetMyList[i].A)</td>
                <td asp-for="@Model.GetMyList[i].B">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.GetMyList[i].B)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

3.HttpGet method

```
public IActionResult GetTable(int num)
    {
        var send_class = new GetChecking();
        var send_list = new List<MyClass>();
        send_class.DetermineNumber = num;
        for (int i = 0; i < send_class.DetermineNumber; i++)
        {
            send_list.Add(new MyClass { A = 0, B = i });
        }
        send_class.GetMyList = send_list;
        return PartialView("_IndexPartial",send_class);
    }
```

Comment: It is working and solution I'm looking for.  To add this, is there any way to send controller two different variables? For example, in ajax, sending variable is just "number". Any chance to like a integer from input and bool from checkbox?

Comment: Of course you could add more variables as query string in url  and connect them with `&`, for example `url: "/Home/GetTable?Num=" + num + "&Value=" + value` , and action `public IActionResult GetTable(int num, bool value)`

Answer (score 0):

I try to this but cant work:

```
@model GetChecking
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div align="center">
    <table id="tablex">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tablex Row Count</td>
                <td asp-for="@Model.DetermineNumber"><input id="number" name="number" type="text" oninput="changeNum()" /></td>
                <td asp-for="@Model.Checking"><input id="mycheck" name="mycheck" type="checkbox" oninput="changeNum()" /></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <div align="center" id="indexWrapper">
        <partial name="_IndexPartial" model="@Model" />
    </div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
        function changeNum() {
            var num = $("#number").val();
            var che = $("#mycheck").val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url:"/Home/GetTable?num=" + num + "&cont=" + che,
                    success: function (res) {
                        $("#indexWrapper").html(res)
                    }
                });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use `asp-for` on  `input` instead of `<td>`. `<input id="number" asp-for="@Model.DetermineNumber" oninput="changeNum()" /> 
    <input id="mycheck" asp-for="@Model.Checking" type="checkbox" onchange="changeNum()" />`. modify js `var che =  $("#mycheck").is(":checked");`